# How to give data to ManyToManyField from view in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hello i am new to django and i am trying to create a page where we can add and participate in various events.

This is the model i created for my database

**model.py**

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Venue Name', max_length=120)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    zip_code = models.CharField('Zip Code', max_length=6)
    phone = models.CharField('Contact Number', max_length=25, blank=True)
    web = models.URLField('Website Address', blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Email', blank=True)
    owner = models.IntegerField('Venue Owner', blank=False, default=1)
    venue_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Event Name', max_length=120)
    event_date = models.DateTimeField('Event Date')
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True,null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, )
    attendees = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True, related_name='attendees')
```

here i am trying to make a link by clicking that link user participate to that Event
but i am not getting how to put the user data in the above attendees field

**view function**

```
def attendees(request):
    Event.attendees.add(request.user)
    return redirect('list-events')
```

*error* : AttributeError at /participate/
'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add'

**link**

```
<a href="{% url 'participate' %}">Participate</a>
```

**url.py**

```
path('participate/', attendees, name='participate')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify for *which* event the user will be added, so the view should look like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
@login_required
def attendees(request, pk):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=pk)
    event.attendees.add(request.user)
    return redirect('list-events')
```

participating should be done through a POST request since it alters entities. A GET request should only be used to *retrieve* data, not update it.

and the `urls.py` thus should contain a URL parameter for the primary key:

```
path('participate/<int:pk>/', attendees, name='participate')
```

Finally the template should thus make a POST request to the path with the primary key of the event:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'participate' pk=event.pk %}">
    <button type="submit">Participate</button>
<form>
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: One can use the [**`@require_POST`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST)
> to restrict the view to only be accessible for a POST request.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easiest way of doing it. As I can understand `Venue` model is saved by the admin(i.e you). If not then you have to save the Venue first.

Now the key point is, in relationship fields, you have to pass the whole inheriting model object.

You can do something like this:

**#in login view**

```
def login(request):
   #your code
   request.session['userID']=userID
   #your code
```

now you can use the session variable (i.e userID) in any view or template

**#participate view**

```
from mymodels import Event,Venue

def participate(request):
     #your GET or POST parameters here
     user=user_model.objects.get(id=request.session['userID'])
     venue=Venue.objects.get(id=venue_id) #OR filter it by any other field like name
     E1=Event()
     E1.attendees= user
     E1.venue= venue
     E1.manager= user
     E1.name= name_from_request_parameters
     E1.description= description_from_request_parameters
     E1.event_date= event_date_from_request_parameters
     E1.save()
```

Tip: use default current date in datefield like
`event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())`